# How can I install argon2 from terminal?

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm having a problem with the use of Argon2PasswordHasher class from django.contrib.auth.hashers.
I'm trying to study its function, starting from encode in a very basic use. When I try to install argon2 from the terminal with: pip install argon2 it shows me a lot of error:

```
Collecting argon2
  Using cached argon2-0.1.10.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: argon2
  Building wheel for argon2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      copying argon2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      package init file 'phc-winner-argon2\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      building '_argon2' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\phc-winner-argon2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\phc-winner-argon2\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\phc-winner-argon2\src\blake2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.obj
      argon2.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.obj
      blake2b.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.obj
      core.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.obj
      encoding.c
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(334): warning C4267: '=': conversione da 'size_t' a 'uint32_t'. Possibile perdita di dati.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(339): warning C4267: '=': conversione da 'size_t' a 'uint32_t'. Possibile perdita di dati.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(347): warning C4267: '=': conversione da 'size_t' a 'uint32_t'. Possibile perdita di dati.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(407): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(409): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(411): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.obj
      ref.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.obj
      thread.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./src/argon2_py.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./src/argon2_py.obj
      argon2_py.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\um\x64 libeay32.lib advapi32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__argon2 build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./src/argon2_py.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\_argon2.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src\_argon2.cp310-win_amd64.lib
      LINK : fatal error LNK1181: non Š possibile aprire il file di input 'libeay32.lib'
      error: command 'D:\\VisualStudio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2
  Running setup.py clean for argon2
Failed to build argon2
Installing collected packages: argon2
  Running setup.py install for argon2 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for argon2 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      copying argon2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      package init file 'phc-winner-argon2\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      building '_argon2' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\phc-winner-argon2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\phc-winner-argon2\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\phc-winner-argon2\src\blake2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.obj
      argon2.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.obj
      blake2b.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.obj
      core.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.obj
      encoding.c
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(334): warning C4267: '=': conversione da 'size_t' a 'uint32_t'. Possibile perdita di dati.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(339): warning C4267: '=': conversione da 'size_t' a 'uint32_t'. Possibile perdita di dati.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(347): warning C4267: '=': conversione da 'size_t' a 'uint32_t'. Possibile perdita di dati.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(407): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(409): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(411): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.obj
      ref.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.obj
      thread.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt /Tc./src/argon2_py.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./src/argon2_py.obj
      argon2_py.c
      D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\nicog\newApi\venv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\um\x64 libeay32.lib advapi32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__argon2 build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./src/argon2_py.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\_argon2.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src\_argon2.cp310-win_amd64.lib
      LINK : fatal error LNK1181: non Š possibile aprire il file di input 'libeay32.lib'
      error: command 'D:\\VisualStudio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> argon2

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It [requires](https://github.com/flamewow/argon2_py/blob/931f21ba9012f30fad436740b94687a58f5f8331/setup.py#L29) OpenSSL-Win32.

Comment: Overall: `argon2`, the latest version [0.1.10](https://pypi.org/project/argon2/0.1.10/) was released in 2015. Seems like an abandoned outdated project.

Comment: The dll they are trying to load is not included in [up to date openssl](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2017-June/005977.html). If you want to get it to work, try an older version from 2015 like 1.0.0q. But as @phd has mentioned, the project is outdated which should be a red flag for anything security related

Comment: I searched it but I continue not to understand where can I find that version of OpenSSL

Comment: @moret12 Conan: the earliest version is 1.0.2s: https://conan.io/center/openssl?version=1.0.2s&os=Windows Found in https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Comment: openssl-1.1.1p: https://mirror.firedaemon.com/index.php?dir=OpenSSL%2F

Comment: 0.9.8: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

Comment: Doesn't matter if you get the libeay32.lib, it will still fail due to Pyinit_argon2 external symbol now found, see here https://techoverflow.net/2022/01/23/how-to-fix-python-cffi-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-pyinit__/

Comment: Better use this python package: https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/